# Как сделать 2 стадии nav панели?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Немного запутался...

Есть навигационная панель в шапке сайта, у которой 2 стадии:

1. Пассивная ( при загрузке )
2. После прокрутки ( см. unbounce.com )

В шапке, помимо стандартных ссылок "Главная", "Услуги", должна быть кнопка заказа, которая появится только в стадии прокрутки.

Как такое сделать?

.nav .scrolled { ? }

Грубо говоря, копия unbounce.com

Добавить в html навигационной панели эту ссылку и делать её видимой только в .nav .scrolled ?

Совсем запутался.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

По всей видимости, вам нужен один из подобных вариант:

**1. Пример с добавлением элемента в разметку при использовании jQuery**

```js
var element = $('.nav');
 
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 200) {
        if(element.has('.link').length == 0)
        element.append('<a href="#" class="link">Купите наш товар</a>')
    } else {
          $('.link').remove();
    }    
});
```

```css
.wrapp {
  height: 3000px;
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #084f70;
  text-align: center;
}
.link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 32px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp">
  <header class="nav"></header>
</div>
```

**2. Пример с добавлением элемента в разметку на чистом JavaScript**

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0];
var link = document.createElement("a");
var linkText = document.createTextNode("Купите наш товар");
link.className = "link";
link.appendChild(linkText);
link.setAttribute("href", "#");

window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    var status = document.getElementsByClassName('link').length;
    if(scrollTop > 200) {
        if(status == 0) element.appendChild(link);
    } else if(scrollTop <= 200 && status != 0) {
        element.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapp {
  height: 3000px;
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #084f70;
  text-align: center;
}
.link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 32px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <header class="nav"></header>
</div>
```

**3. Пример со скрытием/показом уже существующего в разметке элемента при использовании jQuery и css-класса**

```js
var element = $('.link');

window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var status = element.hasClass('show');
    if(scrollTop > 200) {
      if(status == 0) element.addClass('show');
    } else if(scrollTop <= 200 && status != 0) {
        element.removeClass('show');
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapp {
  height: 3000px;
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #084f70;
  text-align: center;
}
.link {
  display: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 32px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp">
  <header class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="link">Купите наш товар</a>
  </header>
</div>
```

1. https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/2vdp8aqp/1
2. https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/2vdp8aqp/3/
3. https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/2vdp8aqp/6/

Comment: Спасибо! А возможно ли подобное без js?

Comment: Т.е. навигация после прокрутки будет .nav .scrolled

А ".a .hidden" будет видимой только при .scrolled

Кстати да

Comment: @Erik Padamans .nav и .scrolled - это просто классы для элемента, с помощью которых в css можно описать правила стилизации и позиционирования элемента. Если при прокрутке вы добавляете класс scrolled, то можете показ/скрытие ссылки (элемента <a>) привязать к нему, например, .nav.scrolled .link {display: inline-block;}

Возможно, как-то и можно сделать без js, но скроллирование (скролл) - это событие, и его нужно как-то отслеживать. Для этой цели и используется Джаваскрипт.

Comment: Спасибо, уже сделал! Да, понимаю. Просто в моем случае нужно было лишь сделать отдельный класс :)